# Can I use the same Monero miner on 32bit and 64bit os?

Tags: compatibility, 64-bit, software-compatibility, cryptocurrency

I'm mining Monero with my raspberry pi and everything's working just fine. Now I found out that the original (by the raspberry community/devs) os (Raspbian) is only 32bit... To increase my RPis performance I want to install [Pi64](https://github.com/bamarni/pi64) on it.

At the moment I'm using the xmrig miner for mining Monero...

My questions is if I could install and compile xmrig on a 64bit os just as I did on my 32bit os or could there be some issues?

---

Note: I already asked this question [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/9954/7846) but I think it's better suited on the Raspberry Pi SE page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first look you aren't likely to have any issues. And because pi64 is based on raspbian it is likely you will have the same setup to compile xmrrig. The only thing that might cause issues is the experimental level of the operating system. I don't know how stable it is compared to raspbain, but I see no reason to not try it out! Good luck!